# Unable to read SObject

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a below array of objects in my LWC

```
   const lineItemsToUpdateArray =  [{"id":"a2323000000EWeRAAW","Licensed_User__c":"0032H00002HWXvzQAH","attributes":{"type":"Proposal_Line_Item__c","url":"/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Proposal_Line_Item__c/a2323000000EWeRAAW"}}]
```

passing the above array to apex

```
await updateLineItems({lineItemsToUpdateArray })
```

passing the same JSON to apex

Apex code:

```
public static void updateLineItems(sObject[] lineItemsToUpdateArray) {

    update lineItemsToUpdateArray;
}
```

It throws below error

> {"status":500,"body":{"message":"Unable to read
> SObject"},"headers":{},"ok":false,"statusText":"Server
> Error","errorType":"fetchResponse"}

Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: I would start by double checking your permissions and API Version.

Comment: I am system admin and have all the permissions required

Comment: Have you tried being more explicit about the property name, rather than using an inferred property name in the parameters object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send an SObject from LWC to Apex, you need to use the following format:

```
{
    "sobjectType": "Proposal_Line_Item__c",
    "Id": "a2323000000EWeRAAW",
    "Licensed_User__c": "0032H00002HWXvzQAH"
}
```

(Note: `Id` not `id`)

Comment: Or, alternatively, they could change that method to use `Proposal_Line_Item__c[]` as the parameter data type.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have tried that but it didn't work